# How can I initialize UILabel in my story board from func viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift

Here i call init for testview controller. What am i doing wrong? I correct for several hours.

```
class FilmTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {


@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var tableViewFilm: UITableView!

var request: Request?
var filmObj: Film?
var arrayFilm = [Film?]()
var imageFilm: UIImage!


override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchBar.delegate = self
    tableViewFilm.delegate = self
    tableViewFilm.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    tableViewFilm.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 36.0/255, green: 49.0/255, blue: 65.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
    var str = "Hello"
    var str2 = "World"
    TestViewController(film: str, str: str2)


}}
```

but at this point the application crashes. I dont understand why.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var labelOne: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!


init(film: String, str: String) { // here film and str not equal nil
    self.labelOne.text = film  // crashes here "found nil"
    self.label2.text = str
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
}
```

It may be impossible to call init to vievdidload? I connected all IBOutlets in Interface builder.

Comment: What is the crashlog? Which label do you want to initialize?

Comment: just move the line `self.labelOne.text = string.title` from `init` to `viewDidLoad` after the call to `super`! Where does the title come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `TestViewController` to

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelOne: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

    var film: Film?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.labelOne.text = film?.title
    }
}
```

Since your `TestViewController` is defined in your Storyboard, you need to initialise it in the following way:

```
if let viewC = UIStoryboard(name: "YOUR_STORYBOARD_NAME", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ID_OF_TEST_VIEW_CONTROLLER") as? TestViewController {
        // your TestViewController should be correctly initialised now
        // and now you can add the film object to it
        viewC.film = YOUR_MOVIE
}
```

You need to use the storyboard ID of `TestViewController` instead of ID_OF_TEST_VIEW_CONTROLLER.

In this way you can also easily prepare your `TestViewController` for display if you use segues:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let viewC = segue.destinationViewController as? TestViewController {
        viewC.film = YOUR_MOVIE
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zept I have added another version which uses a convenience initialiser and is a bit more elegant. You can try it as well :)

Comment: Ok i try now :) Thank you! You really helped me . I tried for several hours to realize  init for uiviewcontroller.

Comment: omg. I have nil, when trying initialized viewcontroller. I called TestViewController(movie) in tableviewcontroller in viewDidLoad and my app crash with log :  fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. But when set Breakpoin on `init(film:Film) {` my movie is not equal nil...

Comment: @Zept Are you sure that all your IBOutlets are connected in Interface builder? If they are not your app will crash

Comment: Yes I sure. May be i can send screenshots  your email?

Comment: @Zept can you just copy the function in which you call this initialiser? To better understand where your problem is

Comment: @Zept update your question and include the code at the bottom of it. It will make it more visible and will also help others understand where you are with this problem right now. Can help to get mor meaningful replies :)

Comment: @Zept try using the second approach which I suggested. Do you still have an error with it?

Comment: Ok, I have figured out what's going wrong. Will suggest a new implementation now

Comment: Basically, your view controller is in storyboard. In order to correctly initialise it (so that all IBOutlets connections from your storyboard are used) you need to use another method. Otherwise, your UILabels are nil (which is exactly the error that you see). Give me 2 mins

Comment: Thank you ! I really want to deal with this problem .

Comment: Try the updated answer. With this approach you define a Film object which will store the necessary information for your labels to display and you will use information contained in it to populate them.

Comment: I was through and segue was done . But I would like to get rid of it through the initialized, to minimize the code. Thank you for the help!

Comment: `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        var DestinationViewController : FilmViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FilmViewController
       
        DestinationViewController.filmInformation = filmObj
        DestinationViewController.imageFilm = imageFilm
        
    }
`

Comment: If you have your view controller in the Storyboard you will have to initialise them using UIStoryboard. That's because all the IBOutlets are defined there. You have two other alternatives:
1) create all user interface programatically (so no IBOutlets)
2) define your user interface in separate xibs.

Generally speaking it is advisable to use storyboards